# Custom filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm experimenting with custom filters and for the life of me I can't get this to work. Its a very basic filter on an ng:repeat that returns the data unaltered. As you can see the table does not populate like it should. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/vh7hV/1/

### HTML

```
<table ng-app ng-controller="TransactionsCtrl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Running Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng:repeat="transaction in transactions | runningTotal">
            <td ng:bind="transaction"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
angular.module('filters', [])
    .filter('runningTotal', function () {
        return function (items) {
            return items;
        };
    });

angular.module('app', ['filters']);

var TransactionsCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.transactions = [1,2,3,4];
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a problem with the filter itself. You've forgotten to provide a value to the `ng-app` attribute:

```
<table ng-app ng-controller="TransactionsCtrl">
```

should be

```
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="TransactionsCtrl">
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/vh7hV/2/)

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I had removed it because of a previous bug and forgot to replace.